# Do these two ways of deleting vector pointers result in the same thing?

Tags: c++, vector, std, erase

I was wondering if in this case I could use the std::vector::resize() function instead of the erase(). I was wondering in the following case whether the ::erase() and ::resize() would do the same thing:

```
struct Foo
{
    int* a = new int[10];
    ~Foo() { delete[] a; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo*> fooVector;

    // FILL VECTOR WITH 100 FOO OBJECT POINTERS
    int i = 100;
    while (--i) fooVector.push_back(new Foo);

    // DELETE LAST 50 FOO OBJECTS
    for (int i = 50; i < 100; ++i)
        delete fooVector[i];

    // ERASE LAST 50 VECTOR ELEMENTS (POINTERS)
    fooVector.erase(fooVector.begin() + 50, fooVector.end());

    // IS THE LAST LINE THE SAME AS
    fooVector.resize(50);
}
```

I was wondering, seeing as though the last 50 elements of vector are dangling pointers, would ::erase() and ::resize() do the same thing essentially? I'm guessing that ::resize() would do ::erase() for all old elements after the position of the last element before the ::resize().

Comment: The erase aproach should be `fooVector.erase(fooVector.begin() + 50, fooVector.end());` (removing +100 from the `end()`)

Comment: @German Ahh, right, I thought I was writing begin() + 100

Comment: BTW you should probably use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, erasing the last elements of a `vector` is equivalent to resizing it.

In both cases the last 50 elements are removed and the vector now has size 50.